# python "del" statment deletes multiple dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, del

i have a problem with the del statement for dicts since i get multiple deletes. So for example my code looks like this:

```
info_dict = {'parent1':{'exon':{'exon1':{'str_0':1, 'end_0':1}, 'exon2':{'str_0':2, 'end_0':2}}},'parent2':{'exon':{'exon1':{'str_0':1, 'end_0':1}, 'exon3':{'str_0':3, 'end_0':3}}}}
print info_dict 
#now i want to delete this key: 
del info_dict.get('parent1').get('exon').get('exon1')['end_0']
#as an result i get this: 
print info_dict 
{'parent1':{'exon':{'exon1':{'str_0':1}, 'exon2':{'str_0':2, 'end_0':2}}},'parent2':{'exon':{'exon1':{'str_0':1}, 'exon3':{'str_0':3, 'end_0':3}}}}
```

As you can see the del statement deletes the right key from 'parent1'. But it also deletes the same key from dict 'parent2'.

In my code i loop through the dicts with:

```
for parent_key in info_dict: 
    "check something and del"
```

If i run the code like above the del statement deletes just one key. But when i loop it, it del multiple keys. I checked my code several times an it is all right. At this point i have no clue what is wrong... Sorry i do not show you the whole code, it seems to big. But maybe someone has an idea what the problem is. 
Thank you

Comment: Why say `info_dict.get('parent1').get('exon').get('exon1')['end_0']` rather than `info_dict['parent1']['exon']['exon1']['end_0']`?

Comment: The code you gave does not produce the result you claim to have received.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: I just ran your code and the `del` statement works correctly, are you sure you did not mistype something in your question or in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your actual code you  are creating *references* to `dicts` so when you change in one place you change all the references.

```
d = {1:{2:3}}

d1 = d # creates a reference so d1 id d
print(d)
print(d1)
del d[1]

print(d)
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: 3}}
{1: {2: 3}}
{} # both empty as both are the same dict/object
{}
```

Now making an actual copy with [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy

d = {1:{2:3}}

d1 = deepcopy(d) # creates a copy/new object
print(d)
print(d1)
del d[1]

print(d)
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: 3}}
{1: {2: 3}}
{} # only d is empty as we created a new object for d1
{1: {2: 3}}
```

Comment: Ah yes! i still do not understand why python does it "wrong" since i use the del statement with an precise description which key it hast to delete. But i see what is going wrong and your answer helped me to fix it. So thank you a lot it already drove me nuts... :)